# 2:1 MUX connected to a D Flip Flop

Tags: flipflop, multiplexer

I have to describe the function of the circuit below which is a 2 to 1 multiplexer connected to a D Flip Flop and even though I understand their functions individually I cannot really understand what the whole circuit is supposed to do. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

[image: circuit]

Comment: What is part number of this mux? It's not mux maybe. The address input is not present and data input too large. The 2:1 mux must address input to have.

Comment: part number that must be used is 74157, there's nothing else that is specified

Comment: Come on think about it. What does it do when EN is 0? What does it do when EN is 1?

Comment: And think about why the FF output feeds back into the input of the mux

Comment: The select pin1 of 74157 is not showed. This pin selecting "load" or "stored" mode.

Comment: You probably meant the “Select” input on the mux, not the “Enable”. The circuit has 3 inputs: D, SEL, and CLK, and one state, Q. The state Q only changes on rising edge of CLK. So on any rising CLK edge 1 of 8 things can happen depending on the present state of D, SEL, and Q. Write out all 8 possibilities and from that surmise why someone would design such a circuit.

Comment: D Flip-Flop with data enable.

Comment: The part numbers are irrelevant, this is a common piece of logic and the circuit behaviour is obvious. What IC’s have been used doesn’t affect the circuits function.